# On Track vs On Tracks

Tags: grammatical-number

I would like to say a project is going well but am not sure whether I should use plural for track(s)
Which is best?
**We are on tracks** vs **we are on track**?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: A Google search didn't help, I wouldn't call that research. Do you have an answer?

Comment: You should show your work and tell us why it doesn't help. Newcomers here are encouraged to do research, show the research, and then ask a question based on what they may have already learned and shared with the rest of us. Otherwise, you are going to get little help with your questions. Simple questions that can be answered by common reference sources will usually be closed. If you try [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=meaning+of+on+track), it should begin to help.

Comment: I don't understand the point of lecturing instead of actually helping.  People using StackExchange are after the fish, not fishing lessons. I answered 70+ questions on SO and never felt the need to judge. Just sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *on track
>   on schedule; progressing as planned.
>   -- [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+track)

*"On tracks"* redirects to on *"track"* - it isn't the phrase.

This is because *"track"* has 2 meanings - as in rails for a train, and also *"A course of action"*. That isn't plural.

Answer (score 2):

"Track" as a noun also means path or "way", as in "I'm standing on the track the deer use to get to the water". When I hear "on track" I think of a project as not having deviated from its planned progress. "On tracks" just doesn't make sense.